# Where can I find a RegEx visualisation tool for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, debugging, plugins, visualization

I'm debugging and commenting someone else's JavaScript code at the moment but there's some fiendish RegEx in it. While my knowledge of RegEx is fairly good, it would help to have a reliable visualiser to show each RegEx string as a railroad diagram or something similar.

- I found a plug-in for Eclipse, for use with Java, at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547429/regex-syntax-diagram) so I was wondering if there was something similar for JavaScript out there.
- It doesn't have to be a plug-in, though something for Notepad++ would be ideal. I checked via Notepad++'s Plug-in manager but the two RegEx tools I could see there weren't very good.
- A webpage which accepted an expression and produced a diagram would work just as well and would save me having to use JSFiddle so much.

Does anyone know if such a tool exists? Or if there is some trick that I'm missing that can make human parsing of RegEx easier?

Comment: I use this for all of my regex testing: http://regexpal.com - It shows if you're valid, and what is acceptable and what isn't. I posted as a comment b/c I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Very neat tool. Even that'll save me some effort in JSFiddle. Feel free to post it up as an answer (with a little explanation for others) and I'll definitely give it an upvote at least :-) Will be interested to see if any other suggestions come in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Regexpr](http://www.regexper.com/) generates pretty nice visualizations of regexes. A simple example:

[image: Sample screenshot from regexpr.com]

And a more complicated example of a regex which attempts to match HTML tags:

[image: A more complicated screenshot]
<sup>(via [tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/))</sup>

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was after :-)

Comment: Incidentally, http://regexplained.co.uk is exactly the same but with permalinks and client side rendering.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that (as of this writing) the two syntax diagram generators differ, perhaps significantly, in their output. See [my comparison in an answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34048619/2502532).

Answer (score 2):

See [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) which includes a tester and explainer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like a really useful breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for all of my regex testing: [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com)

Not technically what you're looking for (maybe see @John Kugelman's answer) but it works nicely to test regEx and display what works/doesn't work accordingly. Simple to use.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer after your comment. I figure it's good to have this in the answers so anyone else looking at this question can see it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Textpression at www.textpression.com. It's free to download and use whilst in development. It doesn't specifically support JavaScript right now, but will do on commercial release.

It has a very intuitive way of visualizing regex.

Disclosure: I'm the author

Comment: From the StackExchange [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Answer (score 0):

Want some more color?

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=Abc%20(%5Ba-d%5D%2B%3F%7C%5Cd)%24)

There you can get an image for clipboard like

[image: example]

for `Abc ([a-d]+?|\d)$`.